# Find these three partial derivatives...

Tags: partial-derivative

Could you please give me hints on the following problem? (I would appreciate it if you give me no solution, just a point/push in the right direction)


If
$$ u-v+2w=x+2z \\
2u+v-2w = 2x - 2z \\
u-v+w=z-y $$
find $ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}},\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}},\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{y}}.$

My initial thoughts were to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$ of every term, but that cannot be right. Also, I've noticed there exists only one $y$ in the bottom equation...is this of any significance?